# Tried to frame a complicated sentence mid conversation this morning and it didn't work out. Wanted to know how to phrase this sentence correctly

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

So I told my colleague this morning. "Can you please stop committing me to projects on my behalf? I have too much on my plate."

What I meant to say was:
"Can you stop signing me up for projects without checking in with me first, I have too much on my plate?"

But I feel like I have heard a native English speaker use the word "commit" in a similar sentence & context before. Can someone correct that sentence for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds perfectly good business-office English to me. We often talk about being committed to projects where I work. There is even a standard joke about the difference between "committed" and "involved".

"Consider your standard English breakfast of bacon and eggs. The chicken is involved; the pig is committed."

Yes I know that's not what you asked. It was merely an illustration of how much this concept of "committed" is everyday language -- at least, it is in software engineering companies in England itself.